# How to get the output of Google Chrome's Network Panel on Developer Tools? VB

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome-devtools

How to get information just like Chrome's Network Panel[Network Panel -> Name] specifically using Visual Basic.

I would like to monitor the network activities and if a name that contains something it will then use it to do something. Like:

```
Dim usercontent as String = Nothing 
If networkname.tostring.contains("user") then 
    usercontent = networkname.tostring.replace("user", "") 
End If
```

Comment: Google Chrome dev tools are not written in .net and they don't have a .net API.  What are you trying to do?  There might be another way.

Comment: @tgolisch I would like to monitor the network activities and if a name that contains *something* it will then use it to do something.

Like:
Dim usercontent as String = Nothing
If networkname.tostring.contains("user") then
    usercontent = networkname.tostring.replace("user", "")
End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what @tgolisch  have said in the comments: "Google Chrome dev tools are not written in .net and they don't have a .net API." Therefore you can't access this area using .net.